# Hey All, How can I increment a value in state stored within an array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble incrementing a part of my state. The issue im having is accessing or targeting the specific value i want to increment which is cuteness. I am new to react and have added the main bits of code relevant to the problem

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
  cats: [
   {
     name: 'felix',
     cuteness: 0,
     img:
       'https://....jpg
   }]
 }

 handleCuteness = inc_cuteness => {
  const { cuteness } = this.state.cats;
  this.setState({ cuteness: cuteness + inc_cuteness });
 };

 <button
   className="btn btn-success"
   onClick={() => handleCuteness(1)}
   value={cuteness}
  >
  Cuteness 
  <span className="badge badge-light m-2">
    {cuteness} 
  </span>
 </button
```

Comment: Puppies doesn't exist in your state....

Comment: apologies that was supposed to be cats, I have edited the post

Comment: Since your cats state is an array, you need to pass the cat's name or id as an argument to handleCuteness, or else you'll never know which one to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to know which object inside the array you want to edit. The example your provided doesn't work at all, would be better if you had a full working example.

But lets assume you have the following state:

```
state = {
  cats: [
    {
      name: 'felix',
      cuteness: 0,
    },
    {
      name: 'garfield',
      cuteness: -1,
    },
  ],
}
```

And you want to update the cuteness of `garfield` on click. What you must do is as follows:

```
const onClick = inc_cuteness => {
  // map the array to find the "garfield" entry
  const updatedCats = this.state.cats.map(cat => {
    // update only the garfield entry and return it
    if (cat.name === 'garfield') {
      return { ...cat, cuteness: cat.cuteness + inc_cuteness }
    }
    // if entry is not garfield, then just return the previous value
    return cat
  })
  // set new cats array
  this.setState({ cats: updatedCats })
}
```

if you need to dynamically choose a cat name you can use

```
const onClick = (inc_cuteness, catname) => {
  const updatedCats = this.state.cats.map(cat => {
    if (cat.name === catname) {
      return { ...cat, cuteness: cat.cuteness + inc_cuteness }
    }
    return cat
  })
  this.setState({ cats: updatedCats })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with an array of objects, in order for you to update the right cat, you need to identify the right object. You should give each cat object a unique identifier. This makes it easier to find the specific cat you want to update.

Update your `handleCuteness` event-handler to accept a cat-id as an argument. This will help us `find` the right cat to update in the array. When setting-up the onClick handlers for your mark-up, you can pass the very same cat-ids belonging to each cat.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    cats: [
      {id: 1, name: "felix", cuteness: 0, img: "blah"},
      {id: 2, name: "samuel", cuteness: 0, img: "blah2"}
    ]
  }

  handleCuteness = (catId) => {
     const catsCopy = [...this.state.cats]

     let foundCat = catsCopy.find(cat => cat.id == catId)
     foundCat.cuteness = foundCat.cuteness + 1

     this.setState({
        cats: catsCopy
     })
  }

  createCats = () => {
     const { cats } = this.state
     return cats.map((cat) => {
        return(
           <div>
               <img src={cat.img}/>
               <button 
                 className="btn btn-success"
                 onClick={() => this.handleCuteness(cat.id)}
                >
                   Cuteness
                   <span className="badge badge-light m-2">
                     {cuteness} 
                   </span>
               </button>
           </div>
        )
     })
  }

  render(){
     return(
       <div>{this.createCats()}</div>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rowandinho you're welcome! Just curious, which solution did you ultimately end up using :)